# Removing unused materialize-css and js code from React App for efficiency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

Materialize-css brings lots of already-baked components for you.
But If you wanna use only 1 component (date-picker) of materialize-css in your react app. Will react gonna remove rest of the un-used components from production build? Or will my react app gonna carry whole materialzie css and js code along the way?

suggest a way if react doesn't remove unused materialize code automatically in production build.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with a bundle analyzer for your build:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-bundle-analyzer

You could view such libraries taking up big spaces in your bundle. You could go from there and tackle your concerns.

After that, you could check out PurgeCSS for removal of unused css: https://purgecss.com/

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to bring in only what you need, rather than purge out what you don't afterwards.

https://medium.com/@mattdlockyer/youre-using-materialize-css-wrong-470b593e78e9

For Wordpress builds, I use sass to compile a custom materialize.css as I'm building the site, and the same with js - I use grunt to include only the components that the project needs. This is a more manual approach.

In your use case, you can follow Matt's article to bring in materialize components at component level in React.

[image]